Shading loss consideration
I am calculating energy yield of a bi-facial / tracking PV system by using

pvfactors_timeseries

modelchain.run_model_from_effective_irradiance


that is the way given in bi-facial example in the PVlib website.
Since pvfactors_timeseries returns effective_irradiance to the plane, I am wondering if removing shading loss is more reasonable. Is it depending on backtracking? If backtracking is true then it does not need to consider shading loss?
If false then?
Please advise which loss that I have to consider in case using the effective irradiance from pvfactors_timeseries.
